# Rigid body overlap instead of pushing during Z scale animation

Tags: collision, rigidbody

I was experimenting with the Rigid bodies for an idea of mine. I hope to achieve animation of cubes falling and extending in the Z space. When the Z scale extends, it fuses with the other cube object. What I want is for every cube to be able to push the others when they expand.

I did another test in a new empty project and it worked almost fine, the problem was barely there. I wonder if has something to do with the Collision Margin. I have tried different values between 0.05 and 0.0001, other than an air gap, there is no change in the overlapping. Note: I always play the animation from frame 0, so I must be seeing an updated version each time.
[image]

Here is the sample project: https://we.tl/t-K45R9NGKj5